# Заполнение 2х массивов целыми и дробными числами через Scanner

Tags: java, циклы, scanner

подскажите как сделать ввод элементов для массивов целых и float чисел через Scanner, чтобы целые записывались в свой массив, а float в другой. И если один из массивов полон, то перестать записывать туда значения. Пока программа выглядит вот так

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int arraySize = 3;
int[] integerArray = new int[arraySize];
float[] floatArray = new float[arraySize];
int integerCount = 0;
int floatCount = 0;

do {
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arraySize && j < arraySize; i++, j++) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            integerArray[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            integerCount++;
        } else if (scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
            floatArray[j] = scanner.nextFloat();
            floatCount++;
        }
    }

} while (integerCount != arraySize && floatCount != arraySize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внешний цикл `while`, `integerCount` и `floatCount` убираем. В цикле `for` убираем автоматическое увеличение счетчиков `i` и `j`, увеличиваем их вручную, когда введено значение соответствующего типа (соответственно, `i` будет вместо `integerCount`, `j` - вместо `floatCount`). Также нужно добавить проверку выхода индексов за границы массива.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int arraySize = 3;
int[] integerArray = new int[arraySize];
float[] floatArray = new float[arraySize];

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arraySize || j < arraySize; ) {
    System.out.printf("Нужно ввести еще %d целых чисел и %d чисел с плавающей точкой\n", arraySize - i, arraySize - j);
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        if (i >= arraySize) {
            System.out.println("Массив integerArray полон");
            scanner.next();  // Игнорируем то что было введено
        } else {
            integerArray[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
    } else if (scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
        if (j >= arraySize) {
            System.out.println("Массив floatArray чисел полон");
            scanner.next();  // Игнорируем то что было введено
        } else {
            floatArray[j] = scanner.nextFloat();
            j++;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ошибка: нужно вводить только целые числа или числа с плавающей точкой");
        scanner.next();  // Игнорируем то что было введено
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integerArray));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(floatArray));
```

Пример ввода-вывод:

```
Нужно ввести еще 3 целых чисел и 3 чисел с плавающей точкой
1
Нужно ввести еще 2 целых чисел и 3 чисел с плавающей точкой
1,1
Нужно ввести еще 2 целых чисел и 2 чисел с плавающей точкой
dfger
Ошибка: нужно вводить только целые числа или числа с плавающей точкой
Нужно ввести еще 2 целых чисел и 2 чисел с плавающей точкой
2
Нужно ввести еще 1 целых чисел и 2 чисел с плавающей точкой
4
Нужно ввести еще 0 целых чисел и 2 чисел с плавающей точкой
5
Массив integerArray полон
Нужно ввести еще 0 целых чисел и 2 чисел с плавающей точкой
1.5
Ошибка: нужно вводить только целые числа или числа с плавающей точкой
Нужно ввести еще 0 целых чисел и 2 чисел с плавающей точкой
1,5
Нужно ввести еще 0 целых чисел и 1 чисел с плавающей точкой
1,7
[1, 2, 4]
[1.1, 1.5, 1.7]
```